# Calculate camera position from 3x4 projection matrix

Tags: projective-geometry

I have a 3 x 4 projection matrix $P$ given that calculates a homogeneous 2-Vector ${\bf i}=(u,v,w)^T$ on some screen (e.g.) from a homogeneous 3-Vector ${\bf x}=(x,y,z,w)^T$ in world space by $P \cdot {\bf x} = {\bf i}$.

How can I calculate the position of the camera in world space from that?

Comment: Dear Jakob, no offense intended, but this forum is for research-level math questions, and I fear that yours isn't quite. You might have more luck at the related site: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for your hint - i really was not aware that there are two maths sites in the stackoverflow universe. i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but just now a colleague told me the solution and I want to share it - maybe it is of some use for anybody else some day.

1. Separate $P$ into a 3x3 matrix $P'$
   (including the first three columns)
   and a vector $\bf F'$ (the last
   column).
2. Invert $P'$
3. The projection
   reference point (i.e., the 'camera')
   is then ${\bf F}=P'^{-1} \cdot {\bf F'} $.

Comment: You should probably mark it as solved then.:)

Comment: I believe this calculates -F, there's a minus sign missing

Answer (score 1):

Check out

Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice in C (2nd Edition) by James D. Foley, Andries van Dam, Steven K. Feiner and John F. Hughes (Hardcover - Aug 14, 1995)

And all will be revealed.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. i will have a deeper look into it, but at first sight the book does not really seem to answer my question.